# How to get actual text in WebDriver without trimming spaces?

Tags: webdriver

Please help me to find a WebDriver method (I use Java) for obtaining a text from an element without trimming its beginning and ending spaces.

HTML for example:

```
<input id="pageBean" title="Elsevier ScienceDirect " value="Elsevier ScienceDirect " type="text">
```

"get" of title or value returns trimmed "Elsevier ScienceDirect". But I need this space!

Thank you in advance!

Ilana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `getAttribute(..)`? I tried `getAttribute("title")` and got the trailing space as you desire. Same for value. Tested with Selenium v2.53.1.

[image: Leading Space]

Comment: You're absolutely right! So silly, but I missed the trim() which was made in the automation code itself. (I remembered that getText() in Selenium returns a trimmed text, so I was sure it behaves the same for getAttribute). BTW is there a way to get not trimmed text by getText()?

Comment: @Ilana I wasn't aware that getText() returns trimmed text, but you could try something like `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", element);` if you want the exact text.